# Show $\text{span}(W_1 \cup W_2) = \{v \in V \text{ with } v=w_1+w_2 \text{ for } w_1 \in W_1, w_2 \in W_2\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

My professor gave our class the exercise (on our own time for fun) to show that the LHS and RHS agree.

By definition, we know $\text{span}(W_1 \cup W_2) = W_1 + W_2$ with $W_1, W_2 \subseteq V$ where $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space. So, the question posed in the title can be rewritten as:

Show $\text{span}(W_1 \cup W_2) = W_1+W_2 =\{v \in V  \text{ with } v=w_1+w_2 \text{ for } w_1 \in W_1, w_2 \in W_2\}$

I have no idea where to start...

Answer (score 1):

You could begin with the fact that elements in span($W_{1} \cup W_{2}$) can be represented as a linear combination of elements in $W_{1} \cup W_{2}$