# If $W_1$ and $W_2$ are subspaces of a vector space $V$, then show that $W_1+W_2=\operatorname{span}\{W_1\cup W_2\}.$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> If $W_1$ and $W_2$ are subspaces of a vector space $V$, then show that $W_1+W_2=\operatorname{span}\{W_1\cup W_2\}.$

**My attempt:**

I took some hints from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3504818/let-w1-and-w2-be-subspaces-of-a-vector-space-v-prove-that-w1-cup-w2-is-a-sub) question and split in two cases.

**Case 1:** $W_1\subseteq W_2$ or $W_2\subseteq W_1$

$$\implies W_1\cup W_2=W_1\tag{WLOG}$$
So, for $w_1\in W_1, w_2\in W_2$, we have
$$w_1+w_2\in W_1\in\operatorname{span}{\{W_1\}}=\operatorname{span}{\{W_1\cup W_2\}}$$
$$\implies W_1+W_2\in\operatorname{span}\{W_1\cup W_2\}$$

**Case 2:** $W_1\not\subset W_2$ and $W_2\not\subset W_1$

So, there exist $u$ and $v$ such that $u\in W_1\setminus W_2$ and $v\in W_2\setminus W_1$.
$$\implies u+v\in W_1\cup W_2\in\operatorname{span}\{W_1\cup W_2\}$$
$$\implies W_1+W_2\in\operatorname{span}\{W_1\cup W_2\}$$

However, this does not show that $W_1+W_2=\operatorname{span}\{W_1\cup W_2\}$.

Any hints or alternate solutions will be appreciated.

P.S.: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1723946/show-textspanw-1-cup-w-2-v-in-v-text-with-v-w-1w-2-text-for) is the same question, but I am unable to proceed at all from the hints given in the answer.

Comment: You have $W_1+W_2\subset\text{span}(W_1\cup W_2)$ but other direction containment is obvious: $W_1+W_2$ is a subspace which contains $W_1,W_2$ so it contains their span $\text{span}(W_1\cup W_2)$. So $\text{span}(W_1\cup W_2)\subset W_1+W_2$.

Comment: I don't understand why they did this? You start with $u+v\in W_1+W_2$ where $u\in W_1,v\in W_2$. That means $u,v\in W_1\cup W_2\subset \text{span}(W_1\cup W_2)$ so $u+v\in  \text{span}(W_1\cup W_2)$. Therefore, $W_1+W_2\subset  \text{span}(W_1\cup W_2)$.

Comment: $\textrm{span}{(W)}$ is the smallest subspace of $V$ containing $W$.So if $U$ be a subspace of $V$ containing $W$ then $\textrm{span}(W) \subset U$

Comment: @AnneBauval it answered my query, thank you!